# Spark with kubernetes instead of yarn

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am writing a spark job which uses kubernetes instead of yarn.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Demo").master(????).getOrCreate()
```

So what should be my master, is it kubernetes or something else

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use `master` as it will hardcode it. Use `spark-submit --master` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I should be in the format of `k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port>`

**From the Doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html)**

> URL with the format k8s://. Prefixing the master
>   string with k8s:// will cause the Spark application to launch on the
>   Kubernetes cluster, with the API server being contacted at
>   api_server_url. If no HTTP protocol is specified in the URL, it
>   defaults to https. For example, setting the master to
>   k8s://example.com:443 is equivalent to setting it to
>   k8s://https://example.com:443, but to connect without TLS on a
>   different port, the master would be set to
>   k8s://http://example.com:8080.

Comment: val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Demo").master(k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port>).getOrCreate()

Comment: it should be like above statement??

Comment: yeah it shoul be as above put your api server host name and port as `k8s://https://example.com:443`